# How can I subtract two row's values within same column using sql query in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

(query access)

This is the table structure:

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| id  |  name  |  sub1  |
+-----+--------+--------+
|  1  |  ABC   |  6.27% |
|  2  |  ABC   |  7.47% |
|  3  |  PQR   |  3.39% |
|  4  |  PQR   |  2.21% |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

I want to subtract `Sub1`

Output should be:

```
+-----+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
| id  |  name  |  sub1   |                                    |
+-----+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
|  1  |  ABC   |  6.27%  |  0      First Rec no need Subtract |
|  2  |  ABC   |  7.47%  |  1.2%   <=(7.47-6.27)              |
|  3  |  PQR   |  3.39%  |  0      First Rec no need Subtract |
|  4  |  PQR   |  2.21%  |  -1.18% <=(2.21-3.39)              |
+-----+--------+---------+------------------------------------+
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: What is the data type of sub1?

Answer (score 0):

This is painful, but you can do:

```
select t.*,
       (select top 1 t2.sub1
        from t as t2
        where t2.name = t.name and t2.id < t.id
        order by t2.id desc
       ) as prev_sub1
from t;
```

This gives the previous value or `NULL` for the first row.  You can just use `-` for the subtraction.

An index on `(name, id)` would help a bit with performance.  However, if you can upgrade to a better database, you can then just use `lag()`.

Comment: hi , what is t2 ?

Comment: Do I need two tables?
But I have no more table

Comment: @Bornanejat . . . `t2` is a table alias for the table you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee consecutive `id` values, then the following presents an alternative:

```
select t.*, nz(t.sub1-u.sub1,0) as sub2
from YourTable t left join YourTable u on t.name = u.name and t.id = u.id+1
```

Change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Comment: what is u table ?

Comment: `t` & `u` are aliases; `YourTable` represents the name of your table.